# How to filter the customized query in Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I want to show the remaining students which are enrolled in the given course but not added in the respective subjects by the teacher.

For example 'students_enrolled = Student.objects.filter(course_enrolled=sub_name.course_id.id)' gets all the students which are enrolled in the given course i.e. (sub_name.course_id.id) and

'students_in_class = StudentsInClass.objects.filter(subject=subject_id, teacher=request.user.id)' have all the students added in the class by the 'request.user.id' teacher and given subject.

Is there any way to show the students which are present in the 'students_enrolled' but not in the 'students_in_class' ??

**models.py**

```
class Courses(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_name
 
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('addCourse')

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, primary_key = True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank = True)
    semester = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank = True)
    session_year = models.ForeignKey(Session, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name = 'session_year')
    course_enrolled = models.ForeignKey(Courses, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name = 'course_enrolled')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user) + " " + str(self.course_enrolled)

class Subjects(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    course_id = models.ForeignKey(Courses, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1) #need to give defauult course
    teacher_id = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject_name
 
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('addSubject')

class StudentsInClass(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher,related_name="class_teacher",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student,related_name="user_student_name",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subjects,related_name="user_subject_name",on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject.subject_name + " and " + self.teacher.user.email + " and " + self.student.user.email

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('teacher','student', 'subject')
```

**views.py**

```
def random_function(request, subject_id):
    # Gets the subject name 
    sub_name = Subjects.objects.get(id=subject_id)
    
    # Gets the course name
    course_name = Courses.objects.get(id=sub_name.course_id.id)
    
    # Get the subjects names linked with the given course
    every_subjects = Subjects.objects.filter(course_id=sub_name.course_id.id)
    
    # Gets the names of students enrolled in the given course
    students_enrolled = Student.objects.filter(course_enrolled=sub_name.course_id.id)
    
    # Gets the names of the students present in the class of the given teacher and subject.
    students_in_class = StudentsInClass.objects.filter(subject=subject_id, teacher=request.user.id)
   
     
                       
    context = {
        'students_enrolled': students_enrolled,
        'course_name': course_name,
        'sub_name': sub_name,
    }
    return render(request,'teacher/random_function.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see students_in_class would return StudentsInClass objects. You can further filter down by using list comprehension:

students_in_class = [each_object.student for each_object in students_in_class]

this would return a list of Student objects. As now both students_in_class and students_enrolled are list of student objects you can check if there are missing students:

missing_students = [student for student in students_enrolled if student not in students_in_class]

This would check if each student in students_enrolled is presented in students_in_class.

However, I don't think that the approach you are using is quite useful as for each student you create a new StudentsInClass. You should consider changing the student field in StudentsInClass to ManyToMany relation. By doing so you would have exactly one object for each Class and it would contain all students.